# SQLExecDirect command is not working same queries

Tags: c++, sql-server

I'm working Visual Studio 2017 and SQL Server 2017 .

I want to do is create a query with C ++ and  that will run it on SQL Server.

```
if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirect(sqlStmtHandle, (SQLWCHAR*)L"SELECT @@VERSION", SQL_NTS)) {
    cout << "Database Already Exits or Cannot Created";
    cout << "\n";
    goto COMPLETED;
}
else {
    cout << "Success !!!";
    cout << "\n";
}
```

I use this sample : https://www.techhowtos.com/programming/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-from-visual-c-plus-plus/

But ,

```
if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirect(sqlStmtHandle, (SQLWCHAR*)L"SELECT @@VERSION", SQL_NTS))
```

on this line , if i'm write

```
if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirect(sqlStmtHandle, (SQLWCHAR*)L"**USE database_name**", SQL_NTS))
```

or

```
if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirect(sqlStmtHandle, (SQLWCHAR*)L"**SELECT * FROM sampletable**", SQL_NTS))
```

or

```
if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirect(sqlStmtHandle, (SQLWCHAR*)L"INSERT INTO sampletable (one,two,three) VALUES (1,2,3)", SQL_NTS))
```

this query is not working .

But ,

if i'm running this queries (some sample) ;

```
if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirect(sqlStmtHandle, (SQLWCHAR*)L"**CREATE DATABASE blablabla**", SQL_NTS))
```

or

```
if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirect(sqlStmtHandle, (SQLWCHAR*)L"**DELETE DATABASE blablabla**", SQL_NTS))
```

Queries are working .

i have a 2 function

```
void run_query(string query);
void create_query();
```

create query function working is normally . generate a query and this query goes to run_query .

What should I do in the run_query() function so that every created query works?

My all codes in here : https://paste.laravel.io/7c693fdb-2dc9-41cc-b183-6e45fd3d9b6d

Thanks for everything :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQLExecDirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlexecdirect-function) can return values besides SQL_SUCCESS when the statement succeeds. For example, `USE` will normally return [`SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO`](http://Processing%20Statements%20That%20Generate%20Messages) to indicate the statement succeeded and that informational/warning messages ("changed database context") were returned. Messages can be retrieved with `SQLGetDiagRec` if desired.

I suggest you consider at least all the "happy path" ODBC function call return values and handle each appropriately, raising an exception with diagnostic information when an unexpected value is returned.